# What parts of word/sentence do native speakers pay attention to when reading/skimming articles?

Tags: reading, learning-methods

Do you pay attention to verb conjugation or singular/plural forms of nouns when skimming articles? I am Chinese. I find that I tend to neglect the changes at the end of words unless I read very slow and force myself to pay special attention to the changes. I think this is mainly due to the fact that in Chinese there are no such changes in words to indicate time or quantity. I want to know when you speed-reading an article, what parts of words or sentences you will definitely not skip.

For instance, for the below sentence, if skimming I would only notice the parts in bold:

> **Rosen**baum had joined us to **discuss how** those ship **sound**s could **affect Arctic wildlife** and how the **result**s of the study
>   would **help scientist**s **track** the **impact**s of **climate
>   change on Arctic ecosystem**s.

But in my mind, I don't picture the event was happened in the past and I also don't picture different kinds of "impacts" or "Arctic ecosystems".